# SQL Server Management Studio - Yes/No value type

Tags: sql-server

So in Access you can choose the column data type "Yes/No" and it will ask you while typing in the information the option "Yes" and "No". Yet, I do not see any of that on SQL Server Management Studio from Microsoft, I've searched around and seen that "bit" is the type, but when I put bit and I go to add information it appears as a normal column to type information. Or should I know myself to put either 0 or 1?

Also, is 0 true or false?

Comment: Just a word of warning: If you intend to use MSAccess as a frontend to SQL-Server, then stay away from bit. Access will try to map that to "Yes/No" fields and fail when the bit-column contains NULL, which is impossible in MSAccess. If you intend this scenario, use int with a constraint to -1 / 0 in SQL-Server, which maps to "Yes" and "No" of MSAccess.

Comment: Do you know about phpmyadmin? Is it bit aswell? what size should I put if it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have a **boolean** data type. The closest approximation is the **bit**. But that is a numeric type, not a boolean type. In addition, it only supports 2 values - 0 or 1 (and one non-value, NULL).

However, SQL (standard SQL, as well as T-SQL dialect) describes a Three valued logic - `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `UNKNOWN`. So **bit** isn't actually the best if you need all 3 states.

When using it, you cannot use that value directly in an if statement for example:

```
IF CONVERT(bit, 0)
BEGIN
    print 'Ok'
END
```

would not parse and end up in error. So, you would need to write it as below;

```
IF CONVERT(bit, 0) = 0
```

Comment: Is it the same logic in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

In MS SQL `bit` is equivalent to a `boolean`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx

Here you can read more about.

`1` would be the equivalent of `Yes` 
`0` would be the equivalent of `No` 
`NULL` would be the equivalent of `Undefined` ( if that exists in Access )

Comment: MSAccess cannot assign NULL or UNDEFINED to a "Yes/No" column. Stay away from bit if you want to use it in Access.

Answer (score 1):

in SQL Server the equivalent to `boolean` datatype is `Bit`. `Bit` can take values 0(false) or 1 (true). If you want to set a default value to your Bit field on creating the table you can set:

```
...
myBoolean Bit, default 1,
..
```